# composer update doesn't update files

Tags: composer-php

I have a local git repo and project where I want to use it.
composer.json in project folder:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type":"package",
        "package":{
            "name":"api",
            "version":"0.1.0",
            "source":{
                "type":"git",
                "url":"/var/www/modules/api",
                "reference":"master"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "api": "*"
}
```

composer install get source from the repo. Then I commited changes in the repository and make git tag "0.1.1"
In composer.json I changed version to "0.1.1"
run composer update:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating api (0.1.0 => 0.1.1) Checking out master
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

But files was not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `package` as the repository type. You'd have to manually change all information inside if something changes.

`package` really only is for the situation where you have code that you cannot add a `composer.json` for, or that is not hosted in version control.

For all other situations, i.e. you have the code in version control, and you can add `composer.json` to it, use `"type" = "vcs"` with the repository URL. Composer then works so much better.

See [the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories):

> **package**: If you depend on a project that does not have any support for composer whatsoever you can define the package inline using a package repository. You basically just inline the composer.json object.

See [the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2):

> **Note**: This repository type has a few limitations and should be avoided whenever possible:
>
> - Composer will not update the package unless you change the version field.
> - Composer will not update the commit references, so if you use master as reference you will have to delete the package to force an update, and will have to deal with an unstable lock file.